# find and replace in PDF using sed and pdftk

Tags: bash, pdf, sed

I am doing a mass find and replace using sed and pdftk to find and replace a word in PDF files.  When I run the following command,

```
sed -e "s/word1/word2/g" test.pdf
```

I get the following error,

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

I tried running sed with,

```
LANG=C sed -e "s/word1/word2/g" test.pdf
```

and it runs but doesn't find and replace the string.

I should mention that I tried uncompressing the PDF using pdftk, running sed, and then recompressing with no results.  I am also running this through MAC OS X bash, but I'm thinking the solution should be relatively the same as Linux command line.

Can anyone offer any suggestions for this?

Comment: Have you seen this Web page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220445/how-to-program-a-text-search-and-replace-in-pdf-files

Comment: As a side note/question: is this part of a mail-merge project of sorts?

Comment: This might also be of interest: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17220/how-to-view-and-edit-the-code-of-a-pdf-file